# angular directive for date validation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, directive

i would like to create a directive that check for null
input on html date filed, and if it does null then reset it to current date.
I have no trouble make this check with ng-change.

HTML code:

```
 <input type="date" class="form-control" id="birthDate"
                 ng-model="vm.bDate" ng-change="vm.dateValid(vm.bDate)">
```

And the code in a controller:

```
  function dateValid(date) {
  vm.bDate = date || new Date();
}
```

This code work perfectly fine, but since i have many date fields in my app i would like to do get the exact same result with a directive.

So i implement a directive:

```
  $element.on('blur', function () {
  var pDate = Date.parse($ctrl.$modelValue);
  if (isNaN(pDate) === true) {
    $ctrl.$setViewValue(new Date());
    $ctrl.$render();
  }
});
```

And the html:

```
 <input type="date" class="form-control" id="birthDate" valid-date=""
                 ng-model="vm.bDate">
```

And when the date is null like when i erase the year for example,
i get an error in the console:

> The specified value "Sun Sep 18 2016 21:41:34 GMT+0300 (Jerusalem Daylight Time)" does not conform to the required format, "yyyy-MM-dd".

What is the appropriate way to reset a date fields?

Thanx

Comment: try `$ctrl.$setViewValue(new Date().toLocaleDateString());`.

Comment: Try this, and it's not reset the field.
No error in the console though.

Comment: It's reset it to no date at all, like: "mm/dd/yyy" i would like to reset the fields to the current date.

Comment: sorry you might need extra parens, e.g. `((new Date()).toLocaleDateString())`.

Comment: Still, same result:
The specified value "9/18/2016" does not conform to the required format, "yyyy-MM-dd".

Comment: If i put the " $ctrl.$render();" at the end then i get this error and without the  $ctrl.$render(); then it's just reset the fields to no date at all, like:  "mm/dd/yyy"

Comment: `if (isNaN(pDate) === true)` is redundant. *isNaN* returns a boolean, so `if (isNaN(pDate))`. ;-) The result of `Date.parse($ctrl.$modelValue)` may well be entirely implementation dependent and unreliable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Directive solution:

```
app.directive('validDate', function ($timeout) {
  return {
    scope: {
      ngModel: '='
    },
    bindToController: true,
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
      element.on('blur', function () {
        // using timeout instead of scope.$apply, notify angular of changes
        $timeout(function () {
          ctrl.ngModel = ctrl.ngModel || new Date();
        });
      });
    }, 
    controller: function () {}
  }
});
```

HTML:

```
<input type="date" 
       class="form-control" 
       id="birthDate2"
       ng-model="vm.bDate" 
       valid-date>
```

updated plunker with both answers: http://plnkr.co/edit/32Ny4rnPreK2dGC5GMFo?p=preview

Yet another directive, which adds ng-blur to the element

JS

```
app.directive('vd', function ($compile) {
  return {
    link: function (scope, element) {
      element.attr('ng-blur', 'vm.dateValid()');
      $compile(element)(scope);
    }
  }
});
```

HTML

```
<input type="date" 
       class="form-control" 
       id="birthDate2"
       ng-model="vm.bDate" 
       vd>
```

plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/U9KtoffbnCXNeAWcWLEC?p=preview

Comment: This is great. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you do not need directives, just validate your input with `ng-blur`:

HTML

```
<input type="date" 
       class="form-control" 
       id="birthDate2"
       ng-model="vm.bDate" 
       ng-blur="vm.dateValid()">
```

JS

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  var vm = this;

  vm.bDate = new Date();

  vm.dateValid = function () {
    vm.bDate = vm.bDate || new Date();
  }
});
```

plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/32Ny4rnPreK2dGC5GMFo?p=preview

Comment: I use to do this with ng-change but as said, since i have a few date input in a different controller i though to save some typing..
I don't have a specific need with the blur, i could use a 'change' event as well or even 'watch'.
There is no way to do this with a directive?